# How to inject vars into the dict used for template by a decorator in TurboGears2?

Tags: menu, controller, decorator, turbogears2

When a method is exposed, it can return a dict used by a template :

```
class RootController(TGController):
    @expose('myapp.templates.index')
    def index(self):
        self.mykey = "foo"
        self.mymenu = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
        self.selected = "item1"
        return dict( mykey=self.mykey, mymenu=self.mymenu, selected=self.selected)
```

This code works fine. Now I would like to encapsulate the menu boiler plate into a decorator like this :

```
class RootController(TGController):
    @expose('myapp.templates.index')
    @menu()
    def index(self):
        self.mykey = "foo"
        self.mymenu = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
        self.selected = "item1"
        return dict( mykey=self.mykey)
```

But I don't know how to write this menu decorator. If I use :

```
def before_render_cb(remainder, params, output):
    return output.update( dict(mymenu=["item1", "item2", "item3"], selected="item1")) 
    
class RootController(TGController):
    @expose('myapp.templates.index')
    @before_render(before_render_cb)
    def index(self):
        self.mykey = "foo"
        self.mymenu = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
        self.selected = "item1"
        return dict( mykey=self.mykey)
```

It will add mymenu and selected into the dict but I don't have access to the instance attribute of the controller (self.mymenu and self.selected)

If I use a decorator :

```
class menus(object):
    def __call__(self, func):
        deco = Decoration.get_decoration(func)
        return func
```

I can have access to the decoration but not to the expose object neither to the controller.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can always access the controller object and method that are handling the current request using `tg.request.controller_state.controller` and `tg.request.controller_state.method`

This should make possible to access the controller variables from the `@before_render` decorator.

Keep in mind that setting variables inside the controller object is not suggested as it is shared between multiple threads. The suggested way to go is to use `tg.tmpl_context` to store temporary variables that are request specific.

You might also be interested in giving a look at [tgext.menu](https://bitbucket.org/pedersen/tgext.menu/overview) to generate application menus

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example for understanding "before_render" decorator:

```
#---=== read this section second: ===---

def make_menu_from_controller(remainder, params, output):
    controller = output.pop('controller') #Here we remove RootController sent by "index" and write it to "controller" variable.
                                          #Only {'page':'index'} left inside "output" variable
    return output.update(dict(mykey=controller.mykey, mymenu=controller.mymenu, selected=controller.selected)) #here we update dict adding "mykey", "mymenu" and "selected" keys. 

#---=== read this section first: ===---

class RootController(TGController):

    def __init__(self): #here we initiate variables, which are not changed during surfing
        self.mykey = "foo"
        self.mymenu = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

    @expose('myapp.templates.index')
    @before_render(make_menu_from_controller)
    def index(self):
        self.selected = "item1"
        return dict(page='index', controller=self) #RootController sends itself
```

As You can see, "before_render" decorator intercepts sent data, works on it and returns another data.
"output" is a local variable for "before_render". We changed and updated it's consistence, then sent it as new data.